# How to put Job Status in the Subject of the email that SNS sends

Tags: amazon-sns, aws-batch

I am running an AWS Batch job as Cloudwatch Event Target and I am using SNS to send a notification email about the status of the job.

I have created a SNS Topic, subscribed it to my email address and set it up as a target it a Cloudwatch event rule.

However, I want the status of the job in the Subject of the email. So in case of success I would need the subject as -

```
* Job Name- Status- Succeeded *
```

And in case of failure -

```
* Job Name- Status- Failed *
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like not supported for SNS topic.

As an alternative select "Lambda Function' as rule target and create a Lambda function that sends email via SES in which you have full control on the email message format, subject etc.

check this out - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-send-email-ses/

Comment: Though this link may provide valuable information it may be broken tomorrow. Please edit your answer and incorporate the condensed extract from your source into your answer so it stays useful without relying on external sources and we all can learn.